# Can a struct be inspected in a proc-macro?

Tags: rust, macros, metaprogramming, rust-macros

I'd like to create a proc-macro that is able to inspect the structure of its arguments.

For example, I may have a struct Foo and then my user calls my macro with something like `frobulate!(Foo)`.  This code then creates a new struct FrobulatedFoo that is a transformation of the original Foo.

This can almost be done via an attribute macro:

```rust
#[frobulate()]
struct Foo {}
```

The frobulate proc-macro can clone the Foo ast and then re-emit the original ast as well as a transformed ast.    The problem with this solution is that Foo and FrobulatedFoo are then defined in the same module.    I'd like to be able to put FrobulatedFoo in a different module, and to allow the user to transform struct's defined in third party libraries.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you want to have the following:

```
struct Foo {
   a: i32,
   b: char,
}

frobulate!(Foo);
```

And that last line would expand to something like:

```
mod frobulated_foo {
    struct FrobulatedFoo {
        frobulated_a: i32,
        frobulated_b: char,
    }
}
```

or some other transformation.

But I'm afraid that is not possible with the current procedural macros. Your macro only has access to the *Abstract Syntax Trees* (AST) that are passed as arguments to the macro, nothing else. No type instrospection or reflection.

If you want access to the definition of `Foo` then the definition `Foo` must be inside an argument to the macro.

Comment: Thanks.   This is the answer I expected, but not the answer I hoped for.

Comment: @BryanLarsen: IIRC there used to be a plugin framework for the compiler to do weird things like that, but I think it is deprecated now. Of course you could try building a `build.rs` script that reads the source code of whatever you want (linking to the internal rustc crates) and generates the required source. I've never done that but I'm quite sure it is technically possible.

Comment: Yes, I looked at how rust-analyzer does it, but it uses a very different AST than the syn crate provides, so for my use case I'd have to do everything twice.   It's definitely a very heavy lift.

Comment: So maybe you should have added weasel words to "it's not possible".  I posted two other "answers" to the question showing it might be possible, but with enough caveats and hoop-jumping that your answer of "no" is still in practice the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very similar problem to the one the [bindgen](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-bindgen/) crate solves, except that it is wrapping Rust code rather than FFI code.

Therefore a solution that uses a pattern similar to the one that bindgen uses should work.    IOW, generate the code in build.rs rather than in a proc-macro.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using 4 crates.

Crate 1 is a macro that saves the AST for a struct in a static variable.

Crate 2 defines 'Foo'.  It invokes the macro in Crate 1.

Crate 3 is the frobulate macro.  It's linked against Crate 1 & Crate 2, so when the macro is run, it has access to all of the fully evaluated data in those 2 crates rather than just the tokens.

Crate 4 is the one that calls the frobulate macro.

The first crate can be a general non-specific crate, but since the frobulate crate has to be linked against Foo, it's not at all.  Which eliminates most, but not all, of the advantages of creating a macro in the first place.

This approach is similar to the approach used in [dtolnay's reflect crate](https://github.com/8BitMate/reflect)